# Calculating LED power

Tags: power, led

Typically, to find power we have to multiply voltage and current, flowing through element.

However, looking at LED specs, numbers does not quite match.

For example, [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32698337715.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6d5fc246lj0o4g&algo_pvid=96c4055d-24ec-45e0-87d4-9794861935a4&algo_expid=96c4055d-24ec-45e0-87d4-9794861935a4-18&btsid=0ab6fab215889564350172890ed809&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) contains the following specs or 3-watt LED:

```
3w LED (GPILED GP-H4545 Chip, made in TW)
DC Forward Voltage: 3.4V~3.6V
Forward Current: 600~700mA 
Lumens: 200~260LM
```

If one multiplies forward current\voltage upper bounds: `0.7 * 3.6 = 2.52`
 which is not `3` (not even that close, considering scale).

What is the proper way to obtain power of the LED and how 3 watts power value for this LED was obtained?

Comment: Why don't you ask the vendor of the LED? The site you linked is not a very reliable source for technical information and I wouldn't try to explain why they advertise products the way they do.

Comment: 2.52 rounds up to 3 using normal rounding rules.

Comment: The 3W figure was obtained from the marketing department.

Comment: What do you expect from Alibaba? 3W is more of a Marketing spec. The Voltage varies due to process variance on Rs while the current limit is average (absolute max) but also depends on heat removal efficacy of your heatsink design.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asks about a device from a supplier that doesn't supply a datasheet. Since no guarantees made by a datasheet can be expected, there's nothing to answer here: Get a device that comes with a datasheet that guarantees operation under the conditions that you need.

Comment: A cursory glance at the specification page tells you this: **LED Chip Model: 1W High Power** and this: **Type: 1w 3w led bead light** - why wouldn't that alarm anyone sensible? I am still yet to see anything electrical for sale on aliexpress or alibaba that looks like anything other than completely dodgy goods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 3W is the maximum power the LED can take. Ideally, the LED would require 700mA of current at 3.3V. That's 2.52W which is less than 3W. So lED won't burn out.

That's why they recommend a protective resistor in series for a LED to limit the current so that you won't exceed its power rating.

Note: I have never seen a LED with this high current consumption.

Comment: Not unheard of; Lumileds' Luxeon Rebel chips have those kinds of numbers and are spec'ed at an absolute max current of 1 amp.